# Accessing fields/methods/constructors of an abstract class in its subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I was trying to work out how to access/use fields/methods of an abstract class in any subclass and I came across this example on the web.

```
abstract class Instrument {
     protected String name;

     abstract public void play();
}

abstract class StringedInstrument extends Instrument {
     protected int numberOfStrings;
}
```

with the concrete example subclass given as

```
public class ElectricGuitar extends StringedInstrument {

     public ElectricGuitar() {
          super();
          this.name = "Guitar";
          this.numberOfStrings = 6;
     }

     public ElectricGuitar(int numberOfStrings) {
          super();
          this.name = "Guitar";
          this.numberOfStrings = numberOfStrings;
     }

     @Override
     public void play() {
          System.out.println("An electric " + numberOfStrings + "-string " + name
                + " is rocking!");
     }
}
```

I have 5 questions pertaining to this - sorry for asking more than one question but they are highly related.

1. Is the super() call needed or even valid?.  There is no constructor given in the abstract super classes
2. Can an abstract class even have a constructor given that it can't be instantiated?
3. Is the keyword "this" necessary in this example concerning this.name?
4. What is the play() overriding here?  When an abstract method is specified in the abstract class doesnt that just tell the compiler the method must be specified by any subclass?
5. If the Instrument class, StringedInstrument class, and ElectricGuitar class all specified fields called "name" and each had specified constructors (if allowed) how would each name or constructor be accessed in the ElectricGuitar class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the super() call needed or even valid?

It is not needed, but it is valid.  All constructor must call a superclass constructor, either explicitly as you have done, or implicitly.  If `super();` wasn't explicitly included, the compiler would have inserted an implicit call for you.

> Can an abstract class even have a constructor given that it can't be instantiated?

Yes, an abstract class can have a constructor.  It needs to be called by any subclass constructor.

> Is the keyword "this" necessary in this example concerning this.name?

"this" is not necessary here, because there is no local variable or parameter in scope, of the same name, that would hide the instance variable `name`.

> What is the play() overriding here?

It is implementing the `abstract` `play()` method.  The `@Override` annotation can be used to indicate that the method overrides or implements a superclass or interface method.  Because `ElectricGuitar` is not `abstract`, it does need to implement `play()`, so `@Override` is not strictly necessary here.  However, it is good practice to include this annotation an all methods that are intended to override/implement a method, so that a spelling mistake or typo doesn't mean that the method accidentally doesn't override another method.

> If the Instrument class, StringedInstrument class, and ElectricGuitar class all specified fields called "name" and each had specified constructors (if allowed) how would each name or constructor be accessed in the ElectricGuitar class definition?

You cannot directly access fields that are hidden above the superclass.  You can access `StringedInstrument`'s `name` with `super.name`, but you cannot access `Instrument`'s `name` with `super.super.name`, because you can't "chain" `super` references.  To access them directly, name them differently.

You can however provide getter methods, differently named, in each class, that will provide access to each class's `name` method.

Comment: This sentence appears to be incorrect: "You cannot directly access fields that are hidden above the superclass." You can access these fields, not through chaining super, but by casting. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @rgettman - Thx for the clarifications.  If the abstract class has its own constructor, can a subclass overload it (with a different parameter list) or override it (something with the same parameter list)

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited, so you cannot override them. However, you can define any constructor you want in a subclass, as long as it somehow calls a superclass constructor, either implicitly, or explicitly as the first statement in the constructor's body.  You can overload constructors by having multiple constructors in a class.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the super() call needed or even valid?. There is no constructor given in the abstract super classes.

If you leave it out, it implicitly calls super() with no arguments.

An explicit call can be useful if you want to call a superclass constructor with arguments.

> Can an abstract class even have a constructor given that it can't be instantiated?

Yes. Because that part of the concrete class still needs to be constructed.

> Is the keyword "this" necessary in this example concerning this.name?

No. It can sometimes be useful to eliminate ambiguity to the compiler or human readers.

> What is the play() overriding here? When an abstract method is specified in the abstract class doesnt that just tell the compiler the method must be specified by any subclass?

The annotation allows the compiler to verify that the subclass is actually overriding a method in the superclass. It's easy to make a mistake in the method name or signature, and accidentally *not* override any method.

When you intended to override an *abstract* method, this helps the compiler point you directly to the mistake.

When you intended to override a *concrete* method, this provides a compiler error that would otherwise not be present. This can significantly reduce our confusion, surprise and hair loss.

> If the Instrument class, StringedInstrument class, and ElectricGuitar class all specified fields called "name" and each had specified constructors (if allowed) how would each name or constructor be accessed in the ElectricGuitar class definition.

Ideally, you'd want to provide a single, private field in the base class Instrument, accessed via an accessor `getName()` defined in the base class.

That said, you *can* access the protected superclass fields, by casting. *NOTE:* Usually this is something to avoid.

```
 ElectricGuitar guitar = new ElectricGuitar();

 String guitarName = guitar.name;
 String stringInstrumentName = ((StringedInstrument) guitar).name;
 String instrumentName = ((Instrument) guitar).name;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Even if nothing is done in default constructor of super class, it is better to call `super()` just in case some other developer define a default constructor and initialize something in it. You don't want to miss that.
2. Yes it can. But you can't call it directly. Defining a constructor in an abstract class indicates that any sub-class should define a constructor that has parameters at least super has.
3. As long as you don't have a variable with same name in a lesser scope, you don't need that but it is suggested to use this, for clarity.
4. Don't think it as `overriding`. You just provide an implementation for an abstract class. The method in abstract class is just a contract. But you must implement it in your concrete class. Your last sentence is correct. If you don't have any implementation, you can't call this method, so it doesn't cause a problem.
5. Please make it clear.

Comment: Not sure how to make it clearer.  If you added "String name;" in the definition of StringedInstrument and ElectricGuitar.  But nvm - the question has been answered.

Comment: In #1 above, if you don't call super() explicitly, it's called implicitly. A superclass default constructor will be called whether you call super() or not.  In #2 above, subclasses are *not* required to define constructors with the same signatures as in the superclass. A subclass can provide fewer constructors, with completely different signatures.